# A lottery game.

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Circular track - $A,B,C,D,E,A$

There are 3 such circular track. Three robots $X,Y$ and $Z$ starts from $A$ on their respective tracks. Whenever a button is pressed the robots can move forward or stay at the same place.

For $X$: probability of going $A$ to $B$ is $x_1$, $B$ to $C$ is $x_2$, $C$ to $D$ is $x_3$, $D$ to $E$ is $x_4$ and $E$ to $A$ is $x_5$.

For $Y$: probability of going $A$ to $B$ is $y_1$, $B$ to $C$ is $y_2$, $C$ to $D$ is $y_3$, $D$ to $E$ is $y_4$ and $E$ to $A$ is $y_5$.

For $Z$: probability of going $A$ to $B$ is $z_1$, $B$ to $C$ is $z_2$, $C$ to $D$ is $z_3$, $D$ to $E$ is $z_4$ and $E$ to $A$ is $z_5$.

Given $x_is,y_is$ ,$z_is$ and number of button presses, How can we calculate the probabilty of the states of the robots? For example the probability of BCA after 100 button presses.

The button is continuously pressed and the player can't see the robots. The player will write down the state on a paper and if it matches the states of the robots, he wins the lottery!!

Comment: Are all three commanded at a time by single press

Comment: Yes we can calculate it

Comment: @NamburuKarthik Yes, All three are commanded at a time by single press.

Comment: For 100 it becomes lengthier but I say it shortly

Comment: I will say for 1 robo so u do for all other similarly

Comment: Hello @s0RRy, it’s been one full day since you asked your question. Do you mind commenting under an answer, or accepting an answer? Thanks.

Comment: @BenjaminWang yeah you are wright

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Just write down the transition matrix $P$ such that

$$p_{12}=x_1, p_{23}=x_2, p_{34} = x_3, p_{45}=x_4, p_{51}=x_5,$$

and all other elements are zero. (We let $1$ represent A, $2$ represent B, etc.)

Let the number of button presses be $n$. Let the initial distribution $v = (1,0,0,0,0)$. Then,

$$\mathbb{P}(\text{at state }i) = vP^n.$$

You can find out similar probabilities for the second and third tracks. The tracks are independent of each other.

Answer (score -1):

First u calculate the probability that it reaches B and doesn’t move next that will be $x_1$.$(1-x_2)$^99 and similarly for it comes to B and stays there for second time then probability is $x_1$$x_2$$x_3$$x_4$$x_5$$x_1$ $(1-x_2)$^94 and similarly u calculate for 3rd 4th 5th and so on because as an example u gave a large no. To me

Comment: Did you forget that the robot might complete many circles and get to B, for example?

Comment: Many means ........

Comment: I calculated for 0 circles 1 circle and told him to calculate the rest as it is simple but lengthier

Comment: I don’t think this approach would work for large numbers of button presses. Even a computer would have trouble using this approach. Perhaps have a look at my answer.

Comment: I did not understand ur solution I am sorry May be I will learn it in higher classes